# typedef the following type : Pointer to a member function Fof "any" class having a member function F

Tags: c++, templates, operators, pointer-to-member

I am actually trying to define the following type : X and Y are types, and I would like to define the template type of pointer to the member function Y F( X ) const of "a" class T.

To do this, I defined the following :

```
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y>
struct GenericFunc
{
    typedef Y (T::*F) ( X ) const ;
};
```

Now if

```
class Fct
{
    public:
        Fct( /* something */);
        double F( double ) const
        {
            // stuff...
        }
};
```

and if I declare

```
Fct thef(/* something */);
GenericFunc<Fct, double, double>::F phi ;
```

I would like to use thef and phi to get a double, but I cannot succeed. Any idea ? What is F is operator() ?

In fact, I could do this :

```
Fct thef(/* something */);
double (Fct::*fptr) (double) const = & Fct::F ; // or double (Fct::*fptr) (double) const = & Fct::operator() ;
double x = 3.14159 ;
double y = (thef.*fptr)(x);
```

but I would like to do it in the generic way, that is, generic on the class T that has a member function F, on the type X of the argument of F, and on the return type Y of F.

Thx a lot

PS : I am using a c++ < c++11, that is why I use typedef inside a the struct, and I would like to stick to that.

Comment: *" would like to use thef and phi to get a double, but I cannot succeed."* What's the (exact) problem you're facing? *"What is F is operator() ?"* I do not quite understand what you're asking. An `operator()` member function is just like any other member function, it just has a funny name.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that I wanted to use it as `double (Fct::*fptr) (double) const = & Fct::F`. And yes, I know that `operator()` is just a function's name, but I was mislead by intellisense's different behaviors when I was trying my thing with or without `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Fct thef;
GenericFunc<Fct, double, double>::F phi = &Fct::F;
double x = (thef.*phi)(1);
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11cfa74c6b01df71)

Comment: Thx a lot ! At some point I have tried this yesterday but had intellisense errors provoked by other stuff...